# What should be done about user Alphonse?

Tags: discussion

There is an unregistered user, [Alphonse](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/42220/alphonse), who continually answers questions with long blocks of text. While a part of the answer may be helpful, the bulk of it is a long rant in something of an essay form:

*"Photons have momentum because that is the way our Universe works."*

I've edited some of his answers hoping he would get the hint, but I think that since he's unregistered perhaps he's not able to see that his posts have substantial edits.

I've since stopped editing his answers but was wondering if there was a better protocol for handling this.

Comment: See, e.g., https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3594/how-to-handle-this-li-zhi-guy

Comment: Yes. Spicy jalapeño bacon... @hby2py

Comment: The usual protocol for dealing with bad answers is: if you think it's bad, downvote, and if you think it's really bad, flag it. Going one step further would entail moderator involvement

Comment: I think @hBy2Py is onto something - that Li Zhi -> Alphonse.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt That's what I thought originally, but the pattern is slightly different. Some of Alphonse's accounts appear to have been used more than once, as they've accumulated a few dozen rep here and there. The many faces of Li Zhi pretty much always only had 1 rep.

Comment: @hBy2Py Li Zhi still has original account with rep similar to Alphonse

Comment: @Mith that's like patient zero, right?

Comment: @ortho Apart from the account Melanie's mentioned, there's this one [ https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/45743/alphonse ]. Can you merge them?

Comment: --- @hBy2Py --- Brian The "few dozen" is now over 500 (on each of the two accounts I know) ;)

Comment: @paracetamol I can't merge them myself, and I don't see a huge point in doing so, unless the user himself wants to. And from what we can see, the user doesn't really care, so it would just be a waste of time.

Comment: @ortho The Alphonse(s) have amassed a significant amount of reputation (over 1100 rep on both accounts combined). I'm not sure what overtures  the Mods have made to Alphonse(s) (but I guess you guys tried already). Maybe sending him one more message and merging the accounts would work (It's just two Alphonses...as far as I know)?  Your call though. Thanks!

Comment: @ortho Or...never mind. I left a comment by his answer to some question on handling/removing gallium; he keeps posting answers elsewhere...but he remains unresponsive. Whoa...instantly know how frustrated you guys are. I take back what I said previously ;P